# LALRPOP doesn't recover after finding an invalid token even though I should have

Tags: parsing, rust

I'm currently reading through lalrpop's tutorial and implementing my own parser. However, error recovery doesn't work. As far as I know, I implemented it exactly as it says in the docs.

I adjusted the `grammar` field, created an error vector and added the error case. But somehow lalrpop is unable to recover and continue parsing.

Based on what the docs say, I assume it just dropped the tokens it can't classify and just moves on, but somehow that doesn't work here. Among other things, the vector with the errors is empty:

Rust code:

```rust
use lalrpop_util::{lalrpop_mod, lexer::Token, ErrorRecovery};
lalrpop_mod!(pub swip);

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum TokenT {
  TWhitespace,
  TNumber,
  TError,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct SwipToken {
  pub token_type: TokenT,
  pub value: String,
}

impl SwipToken {
  pub fn new(token_type: TokenT, value: String) -> SwipToken {
    SwipToken { token_type, value }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let mut errs: Vec<ErrorRecovery<usize, Token, &'static str>> = Vec::new();
  let parser = swip::SwipParser::new();

  let input = "1 + 2";
  let result = parser.parse(&mut errs, input);
  println!("Length of errors: {}", errs.len());
  for err in errs {
    println!("Error: {:?}", err);
  }
  match result {
    Ok(result) => {
      println!("Result: {:?}", result);
    }
    Err(err) => {
      println!("Error: {:?}", err);
    }
  }

}
```

lalrpop:

```
use lalrpop_util::{lalrpop_mod, ErrorRecovery, ParseError};
use crate::{SwipToken, TokenT};

grammar<'err>(errors: &'err mut Vec<ErrorRecovery<usize, Token<'input>, &'static str>>);

pub Swip: Vec<SwipToken> = {
  (Lexer)*
}

Lexer: SwipToken = {
  Ws => SwipToken::new(TokenT::TWhitespace, "".to_string()),
  Number => SwipToken::new(TokenT::TNumber, <>),
  ! => {
    errors.push(<>);
  SwipToken::new(TokenT::TError, "".to_string())}
}

Ws: () = {r"[\s\t\r\n]+" => ()};
Number: String = r"[0-9]+" =>String::from(<>);
```

Output of the code:

```
Length of errors: 0
Error: InvalidToken { location: 2 }
```

I would be grateful if someone could explain this to me better and solve the problem